# NodeJs - Lambda - Enable Cors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, apollo-server

I have a nodejs lambda function deployed on aws which exposes a lambda endpoint via API Gateway.
The endpoint is [here](https://3h5e2m2b1a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test?query=%7B%0A%09addNumbers(number1%3A1%2C%20number2%3A55)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) and allows you to access the graphiql endpoint.

When I try to call this endpoint from my react application - I am getting cors errors

```
Failed to load https://3h5e2m2b1a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test?: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

On checking the response from Lambda - it doesn't contain the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

I added the following in lambda.js to try and enable cors but it doesnt seem to work.

```
    const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./src/app');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors()); // enable `cors` to set HTTP response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);
```

The nodejs code for my lambda function is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Hry3waLffFu4PBVrqOb7GbZg0WMiS6d/view?usp=sharing)

Does anyone have any ideas on what I need to do to enabled cors on my nodejs function?
I have enabled cors on the API Gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how `express-graphql` works but if it responds back with without forwarding it to the next middleware `app.user(cors())` will never get hit. Because what you do is

```
var app = express();
app.use('/', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
// then
app.user(cors())
```

Try calling cors before you use `graphqlHTTP` something like

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use('/', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
```